# I am trying to make a simple password program in python at pycharm, when I give if statement it gives a error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("invalid password")
print("Hello, please enter the password to continue")
var = input('Enter password:')
if var != ("password")
print("invalid password")
```

please help me with this

Comment: please add the full error that you are getting

Comment: That isn't valid Python syntax. Read up on how if statements should look

Comment: you are missing the colon to indicate the `if` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python the colons are a must:

```
print("invalid password")
print("Hello, please enter the password to continue")

var = input('Enter password:')

if var != ("password"):
    print("invalid password")
```

This'll work.